# Python string formatting: padding negative numbers

Tags: python, number-formatting

I would like to format my integers as strings so that, without the sign, they will be zero-padded to have at least two digits.

For example I want

```
1
-1
10
-10
```

to be

```
01
-01
10
-10
```

Specifically, I want different minimum string lengths for negative numbers (3) and non-negative numbers (2). Simple number padding as detailed [here](https://pyformat.info/#number_padding) is insufficient. Is this possible?

Comment: See http://pyformat.info, in particular [padding numbers](https://pyformat.info/#number_padding)

Comment: @PeterWood I've read that webpage over and over again, nothing in there address my problem, which is that I require different minimum length strings for positive and negative numbers respectively.

Comment: put what you have tried in the question, and explain why it is inadequate.

Comment: @PeterWood Thanks. Understood. This is the first question I asked so apologies for the incomplete question. It would be greatly appreciated if comments worked too.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you could use `str.format`, but adding 1 to the size to take the negative number into account here:

```
l = [1,-1,10,-10,4]

new_l = ["{1:0{0}d}".format(2 if x>=0 else 3,x) for x in l]

print(new_l)
```

result:

```
['01', '-01', '10', '-10', '04']
```

it works because `format` accepts nested expressions: you can pass the size (`{:02d}` or `{:03d}`) as a format item too when saves the hassle of formatting the format string in a first pass.

Answer (score 7):

According to [here](http://java2s.com/Tutorial/Python/0100__String/Ablankmeansthatablankshouldbeputinfrontofpositivenumbers.htm), you need a space before the type descriptor, so both

```
'% d'%(1)
```

and

```
'{: d}'.format(1)
```

result in (notice the space)

```
' 1'
```

aligning nicely with the result of the above called with -1:

```
'-1'
```

Answer (score 1):

The most concise, although maybe a bit unreadable, way that I can think of (at least in Python 3) would be a [formatted string literal](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#f-strings) with nested curly braces, similar to the accepted answer. With this, the example from the accepted answer could be written as

```
l = [1, -1, 10, -10, 4]
new_l = [f"{x:0{2 + (x < 0)}d}" for x in l]
print(new_l)
```

with the same result:

```
['01', '-01', '10', '-10', '04']
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `zfill`:

```
inp_list = [1,-1,10,-10,4]

out_list = [str(n).zfill(3 if n<0 else 2) for n in inp_list]

print(out_list)
```

result:

```
['01', '-01', '10', '-10', '04']
```

Answer (score -1):

Use `"{:03d}".format(n)`. The 0 means leading zeros, the 3 is the field width. May not be *exactly* what you want:

```
>>> for n in (-123,-12,-1,0,1,12,123, 1234):
...   print( '{:03d}'.format(n) )
... 
-123
-12
-01
000
001
012
123
1234
```

Answer (score -1):

`zfill` actually pads with zeros at the left and considers negative numbers.

So `n.zfill(3 if n < 0 else 2)` would do the trick.

Comment: `zfill` is a method of `str` class, `n` is an integer in your example. This can't work