# Using fmtlib, zero padded numerical value are shorter when the value is negative, can I adapt this behaviour?

Tags: c++, negative-number, fmt, zero-padding

I am using [fmtlib](https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt) to format strings and numeric values but I have problem with negative integers.
When I pad the value with zeroes, I expect a consistent number of zero no matter the sign of the value.

For instance, using a padding of 4, I would like the following:

- 2 to be returned as "0002"
- -2 to be returned as "-0002"

fmtlib's default behaviour is to take into account a prefix lenght (i.e. the sign "-") into the padded length which means that -2 is returned as "-002"

Here is an example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "fmt/format.h"

int main()
{
    std::cout << fmt::format("{:04}", -2) << std::endl;
}
```

will output: `-002`

Is there a way to toggle this behaviour or a different way to zero-fill values to get my expected result?

Thanks for any help,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's certainly nothing in the documentation for either fmt or Python's `str.format` (which fmt's syntax is based on). Both only state that padding is "sign-aware".

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42114875/1863938) asks for the same functionality for Python's `str.format`. The accepted answer there is to move the length to an argument, and make it one larger if the number is negative. Translating that to C++:

```
for (auto x : { -2, 2 }) {
    fmt::print("{0:0{1}}\n", x, x < 0 ? 5 : 4 ); // prints -0002 and 0002
}
```

To break the format syntax down:

```
{0:0{1}}
 │ │ └ position of the argument with the length
 │ └── "pad with zeros"
 └──── position of the argument with the value
```

https://godbolt.org/z/5xz7T9

Comment: Thanks, I was afraid I would have to do this in a manual way... However using the nested syntax for formatting the padding, the result won't look too bad.